# Route open as a full page instead of opening in same page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react router for a SPA Dashboard. I have these two routes(**Routes.js**) in dashboard right now. Also, a separate route in **App.js** for landing page.

Now it works fine as expected when it loads and when I click different routes. For example, When I click customers route(in sidebar), it open the customers section on the same page in right side. But, when I refresh the customers page `localhost:5000/customers`, now it opens as a separate page. How can I solve this.

I tried debugging it but still no luck.
Here's an example : https://github.com/gouravthakur39/MRE
Unfortunately can't reproduce it in code sandbox

**Routes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard";
import Customers from "../pages/Customers";

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" exact component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/customers" exact component={Customers} />
    </Switch>
  
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

**Part of App.js**

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from "./private/PrivateRoute";

import Landing from "./pages/Landing";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Customers from "./pages/Customers";

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/customers" component={Customers} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "open the customers section on the same page in right side" and "now it opens as a separate page". It's also unclear how these two code snippets relate to each other, if they do at all. Why are you rendering duplicate routes? Where is `Routes` rendered? I get the feeling you've not provided all the relevant code for this issue. If possible can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Routes is rendered inside main content 
```
<div className="layout__content-main">
                <Routes />
 </div>
```
So basically, the routes in App.js is required to render /home route which displays dashboard, and routes in routes.js is required to render dashboard routes like: customers, products etc.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question or clear anything up at all. What is "main content"? I still just see two separate sets of duplicate routes and no relationship. In other words I'm saying we need more context. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese can you please take a look at the MRE.
https://github.com/gouravthakur39/MRE
Unfortunately, can't reproduce it in code sandbox.

Comment: I see, based on your code and the description on the `Dashboard` component it sounds like you want `Dashboard` and `Customers` to render "nested" in the "/home" path. Is this correct? Why can't you reproduce it in a codesandbox?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, that's right. I am getting some errors on code sandbox. Will try again to post a code sandbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question/Issue

Based on your code and the description on the `Dashboard` component it sounds like you want `Dashboard` and `Customers` to render "nested" in the `"/home"` path.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <p>I want to open dashboard and customers here when clicked</p>
      <p>
        Right now, when you click customers, it will open it in new page and not
        here.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is because `Home` is rendering the `Dashboard` on the same `"/home"` path, and the sidebar is linking to a "/customers" path at the root router level. This `Customers` component is *outside* the nested home/dashboard component.

## Solution

### App

For this the root `"/home"` in `App` needs to ***not*** exactly match in order for it to render nested routes. Remember also that in the `Switch` component that path order and specificity matter. Order the paths from *more* specific to *less* specific, i.e. "/home" is more specific than "/" and should be ordered higher/before. The `"/customers"` route/path should be removed since it will be rendered by `Home`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

### Routes (*rendered by `Home`*)

Use the `useRouteMatch` hook to gather the current matched `path` value and build the nested routes. Remember the path order and specificity rule for the `Switch`.

```
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Routes = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/customers`} component={Customers} /> // "/home/customers"
      <Route path={path} component={Dashboard} />                // "/home"
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

### Sidebar (*rendered by `Home`*)

Use the `useRouteMatch` hook to gather the current matched `url` value and build the nested links.

```
import { Link, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = () => {
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={url}>Dashboard</Link>                // to "/home"
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/customers`}>Customers</Link> // to "/home/customers"
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit route-open-as-a-full-page-instead-of-opening-in-same-page]